# Describing two people who are absolutely disproportionate in size

Tags: idioms, expressions

I need an idiom / expression / simile in AmE which can indicate a major difference between a couple / two people when they are not at all similar in size (when one of these two is much smaller than the other one.)
I.e. how would you describe two people (e.g. a couple) which are absolutely disproportionate in size?
If I'm not mistaken, there is a Turkish idiom which says:

> - They're like an elephant and a chicken.

I was wondering how would an American convey such a message in everyday speech?

Comment: The literal translation is colourful, sounds creative and is perfectly easy to understand.

Comment: Is there any more common hyperbole in English to imply that @JamesK?

Comment: not that I can think of. You can take any two things that are very different in size.

Comment: How about just saying: "**they're absolutely disproportionate in size**" @JamesK? Does it sound easy to understand to you?

Comment: sure but why not "completely different in size" if you don't want to use a simile, or "They are little and large".

Comment: Does it sound clearly natural and idiomatic if I just say: "they are little and large"?

Comment: From the Bible you get **David and Goliath** although this references more than just their unequal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked what an *American* would call this, and although I'm a native British English speaker, I'm fairly certain there isn't a US term for this. The concept of a couple where one is fat and the other is thin is a really common trope on US television, from *The Honeymooners* to *King of Queens*, *The Simpsons* and *Family Guy*... if they had a phrase for it, we'd have heard it.

Two people who are seemingly mismatched are sometimes referred to as an "odd couple". This doesn't only refer to size or weight, but if you said it about a couple who were markedly different in size I think it would be clear what you meant. Another similar idiom is "strange bedfellows". Again, this could refer to anything characteristic that makes two people seemingly an odd match.

There is a British expression to describe something that looks too small because it is next to something big - "it's like a pea on a drum". I've not heard it used about *people* before, but if someone said "they are like a pea *and* a drum" I'd get that it was a variation of that idiom.

I can't think of any specific idioms about the difference in two people's size or weight. Creative writers would probably think up their own. "An elephant and a chicken" is certainly understandable to me, but it definitely doesn't sound English in origin. It sounds like what it is - a translation of an idiom from another language.

To be clear, comments about people's weight or size are generally considered very rude. I'm not endorsing "fat shaming".